# Solr query API is asking for basic auth. Any way to make it public?

Tags: solr

We want to use Solr for a public search widget on a website we maintain. We have the website crawled and the data posted to a Solr core, but the search API is currently asking for the admin account's username and password with each request.

Any way to turn that off? Have the search public but all administration still private? I wasn't able to find anything in the documentation or in searching around.

Comment: Have you seen https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/deployment-guide/securing-solr.html ? Generally, you should have a service in front of Solr regardless, only allowing the queries/etc. you expect (i.e. a small controller that makes the query to the Solr server and returns the fields you want to expose).